# Using different data series as static labels for columns of column chart

Tags: google-visualization

I presently have a column chart that displays the quantity of a particular product sold as a percentage of all sales. I would ideally like to label each column with the actual value of product sold which I have as an additional series of data.
Is there any way to do this? The closest I've come is to have a line chart with two different vertical axes but I really want something with the columns - and the data labels statically displayed.

Many thanks in advance for help on this.

Comment: If the answer below worked for you, please click the check mark below the up/down-vote arrows in the answer so that other people can see that this solved your issue. If my answer was not clear enough, or if you are still having issues, please add a comment to the answer explaining what that issue is/what isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the {v: .2, f: '234 units'} to differentiate between the value (20%, what's plotted), and the format that's displayed on mouseover (234 units, what's shown when you highlight the data).

For instance:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Product');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent');
  data.addRows([
    ['A', {v: .1, f: '123 units'}],
    ['B', {v: .2, f: '234 units'}],
    ['C', {v: .3, f: '345 units'}],
    ['D', {v: .4, f: '456 units'}],
    ['E', {v: .5, f: '567 units'}],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,{
        width:600,
        height:400,
        vAxis: {
          format:'#,###%'
        }
      }
          );
}
```

I think this is what you're looking for. Let me know if you are looking for something different.